# How to cascade delete only on join table using Entity Framework Code First Fluent API

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I'm trying to map an existing database using Entity Framework Code First Fluent API. I'm struggling on a situation with a many-to-many relationship and cascade delete.

Here's my two POCO classes:

```
public class Foo
{
  public int FooId;
  public string FooDescription;
  public IList<Bar> Bars;
}
public class Bar
{
  public int BarId;
  public string BarDescription;
}
```

For now, I only have a navigation property from `Foo` to `Bar`. That's because in my real scenario, it doesn't make sense for anyone to go from `Bar` to `Foo`. The relationship from `Foo` to `Bar` is actually 0,n which means one instance of `Foo` do not require instances of `Bar`.

My existing database has a join table between those two tables. This table looks like this:

```
create table Foo_Bar(
FooId int not null,
BarId int not null
);
```

Because I prefer to not create such a POCO class in my project, I mapped the table like this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Foo>()
  .HasMany(t => t.Bars)
  .WithMany()
  .Map(m =>
  {
    m.ToTable("Foo_Bar");
    m.MapLeftKey("FooId");
    m.MapRightKey("BarId");
  });
```

That works perfectly for inserts. Entity insert on Foo and then on the existing `Foo_Bar` table.

But when I delete a `Foo`, I would like to delete the records on the join table but not on the child table. Meaning I want to delete records on `Foo_Bar` but not to extend this cascade to `Bar`.

Is such a mapping possible? I should mention that on my context I removed both `OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention` and `ManyToManyCascadeDeleteConvention` because 99% of the times I won't be using cascade delete. This is one specific situation.

By tracing the SQL generated by Entity Framework, I also noticed that if I retrieve a `Foo` instance and set all Bars inside it to EntityState.Deleted, EF will delete both records in `Foo_Bar` and `Bar`. One last thing I should mention is that I'm working in a disconnected scenario.

I tried to search this over but it seems I'm not using the right keywords as I could not find anyone in such a situation. At this point the only solution I see is to `Map` a `FooBar` class but I'd hope there's a way to do this.

**--Edit**

It appears that my approach to delete was wrong at first. When I tried deleting I wasn't passing the instance of `Foo` with its list of `Bar` filled. After that change, Entity Framwork creates a delete statement for every `Bar` on the list. I still have problems with updating like adding and removing items at the same time. Will do more tests and post here.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> But when I delete a Foo, I would like to delete the records on the
>   join table but not on the child table. Meaning I want to delete
>   records on Foo_Bar but not to extend this cascade to Bar.
>
> Is such a mapping possible?

This is actually *the only* mapping that is possible. You cannot extend cascading delete to the `Bar` table because in the relationship (from database schema perspective) the `Foo_Bar` join table is the *dependent* in the relationship and `Bar` is the *principal*. Generally cacscading delete is only in effect if you delete the principal but not when you delete the dependent.

So, you don't need to worry that a `Bar` could be deleted when you delete a `Foo` and you don't have to apply any special setting for this.

But you have a problem when you have removed the `ManyToManyCascadeDeleteConvention`. It acts globally for the whole model and there is no option to turn on cascading delete again for a specific many-to-many relationship. (There is no `WillCascadeOnDelete(true)` for many-to-many relationship like there is one for one-to-many or one-to-one relationships.)

Are you sure that removing the `ManyToManyCascadeDeleteConvention` is really required in your model? I never encountered a model where it would make sense to *not* delete the related entries in the join table when one of the joined entities (`Foo` or `Bar`) is deleted.

Comment: I agree with you. It's the only possible mapping. I don't remember why I specified that when I wrote it. As for the need to remove the convention, well, I have one scenario where one end of the many to many relationship is a table with records associated with business logic. The user cannot edit its records. By not creating a cascade delete on that end even if someone tries to delete a record by mistake, nothing will break. But I guess this is indeed an exception. For now I'll enable the convention and handle the exceptions some other way. Thanks.